How to bind a localhost port to a service via a Gateway without Host header
in our organization, we have a lot of services that hardcode sending requests to something like localhost:12345 from our previous service mesh solution. This pattern is in broad enough codebases that I'm trying to find a way to replicate this using Istio. The goal is to make it so that requests on a Kubernetes pod for localhost:12345 make its way through to a upstream configured via Istio.
This is documented in the docs for Sidecar however, there's one other complexity in our setup that seems insurmountable -- we need to have our traffic support going across an Istio Gateway. This seems to make the entire house fall down.
Before getting into details of what has been tried, thinking about it broadly, I can't see how this could work. The client pod is set up with a Sidecar to bind localhost and point to VirtualService routed to a ServiceEntry with the Gateway's hostname. There are two results to this:

The client envoy leverages the default route-discovery-service route config to route the request to the gateway -- this leverages the Host / :authority header.
That request has to include the Host / :authority so that the Gateway instance can route to the appropriate Gateway CR.

There doesn't seem to be something on the Sidecar I can configure to say "requests on this port should adopt this Host".
What worked
I was broadly able to make it work via a Sidecar like:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Sidecar
metadata:
  name: default
spec:
  egress:
    - hosts:
        - "default/foo.example.com"
      captureMode: NONE
      port:
        number: 8000
        name: frontend-httpbin
        protocol: HTTP2
      bind: 127.0.0.1

with the big caveat that requests must include the `Host header, such as:
curl -H "Host: foo.example.com" localhost:8000

Without the Host header, I think two things happen

The Envoy sidecar running on the client pod is listening on port 8000, but does not know that it should route to the Gateway, because it does that routing based on the Host. Because of that, the curl returns with a no upstream error (sorry forgot to capture the exact line)
Assumption: If we were able to route the request appropriately, without the client Envoy injecting the Host header, the request would get a similar issue once it got to the gateway. The gateway wouldn't have any of the information on the port or otherwise to route the service otherwise

Overall question
Is there a way to make this happen? So that requests to localhost which currently route to a specific service will do the same in Istio via a gateway, without any application code changes?

I have cross-posted this to GitHub Discussions as the SO tag does not have much engagement: https://github.com/istio/istio/discussions/53901
